# Why is task_struct identified with PerCPU?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The problem's cause is something I found in an article. The PerCPU variable creates a separate copy of the variable for each CPU. This allows multiple CPUs to work on their own copies without causing interference. For instance, the `current_task` variable for the current process is declared as PerCPU.

```c
struct task_struct;

DECLARE_PER_CPU(struct task_struct *, current_task);

static __always_inline struct task_struct *get_current(void)
{
  return this_cpu_read_stable(current_task);
}

#define current get_current
```

However, I think the article suggests that the PerCPU flag is meant for multiple CPUs to simultaneously work on an object. For example, in memory management, the `kmem_cache_cpu` uses the `__percpu` macro to manage `current_slab` synchronously. I'm not entirely sure if `__percpu` and `DECLARE_PER_CPU` have the same meaning in the Linux kernel.

I'm puzzled as to why `current_task` is declared this way. Is it done to enable quick access to the 'task_struct' structure from the CPU? Can multiple CPUs work on a thread or a single-threaded process at the same time in Linux? The more crucial question is, could I be mistaken about PerCPU?

I'm new to learning the Linux kernel, so my question may be somewhat vague. Please bear with me.

> Tag: Here is the link to the article I mentioned: https://time.geekbang.org/column/article/96623

Comment: The website you linked isn't in English and my translate app isn't working right now so I can't verify anything about the article. But my understanding is that per cpu isn't for cpus to "simultaneously work on [the same] object". It's because each CPU can work on its own thread and needs its own set of kernel-level variables to do their job. Each `current_task` is independent; they could be working on entirely separate processes or they could be servicing threads for the same app; depends on scheduling. So to give each cpu their own `current_task` upon startup, you use `DECLARE_PER_CPU`.

Comment: The `__percpu` macro doesn't really do much by itself. It's just for debugging and semantic checking by "sparse".